# Rewrite rule to modify dynamic url's

Tags: dynamic, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to create a rewrite rule to modify a dynamic url.

The reference (nie1000857) at the end of the url is the only dynamic part.

"fulldetails?" needs to be inserted as shown below.

- https://www.estateagent.net/property-to-rent/nie1000857
- https://www.estateagent.net/**fulldetails?**property-to-rent/nie1000857

So far I have:

```
      <rule name="Add fulldetails?" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="^property-to-rent(.?)" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url="fulldetails?property-to-rent/"/>
      </rule>
```

However I can't work out how to extract the dynamic part of the url(nie1000857) and add it to the end of the rewrite url.

Any help/advise would be greatly appreciated and apologies if I have missed something obvious within Microsoft's documentation.

I am a total beginner with creating rewrite rules.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

Thought Id post the answer for anyone trying to achieve the same.

```
  <rule name="Add fulldetails?" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^property-to-rent/(.+)" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="fulldetails?property-to-rent/{R:1}"/>
  </rule>
```